# Using strftime with node.js to format date time

Tags: node.js, datetime, package, strftime

I'm recently been exploring node.js and I'm still confused of why require works one way and not the other.

Version of node: 0.12.5

Goal: format date time using strftime package

**What works:**

```
var strftime = require('strftime');

function time(){
    var d = new Date();
    return strftime('%Y-%m-%d: %H:%M', d); 
}
```

**What does not work:**

```
var strftime = require('strftime');

function time(){
    var d = new Date();
    d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d: %H:%M'); 
}
```

Throws and error stating that strftime is undefined.Can someone explain why? strftime [API](http://hacks.bluesmoon.info/strftime/usage.html) shows that the second method is a valid example.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the wrong docs. When you run:

```
npm install strftime
```

You're actually getting [this library](https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime), not the one you're linking.

Comment: On a side note, extending native objects is at the very least [a controversial matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) which is probably one of the reasons why the syntax is not present in the newer library. I would've gone with the first example anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification